What do answers that feature a LLM based text have to include as well to not be deleted?
LLM-based answers are in general not trustworthy for a multitude of reasons.
However, I still think that in some cases an answer could feature a LLM-based answer when OP asks for one.
Example.: Are interpretations that LLM (ChatGPT) provides for Genesis 1,7 biased toward Theistic Evolution?
.
In such a case I think that an answer could feature text from a LLM, to prove such a bias.
BUT what does such an answer have to do as well to not be deleted?
I guess part of the discussion could still be if there is a question that warrants an LLM text part in an answer.
Context is a discussion in the comments of this question: How can Large Language Model AIs help with Hermeneutics?

Questions should not be asking for that. That's just not what this site is for.

@curiousdannii I think there is still a distinct difference between my question here and the supposed duplicate. The referenced question talks about answering a question with only or mostly LLM. I'm making the case that there might be answers where it makes sense to add LLM text but that the answerer has to do more than just use LLM to answer the question.

The current community guidelines are that GenAI basically isn't allowed, other than for undetectable proof reading. If you'd like to make a case that it should be allowed please do so in the original question. If you convince the community then we can discuss guidelines for its use.
